# Nested UNWIND - selective behaviour for non-lists. How is this possible?

Tags: neo4j, syntax-error, runtime-error

This has been driving me mad, specifically as it breaks my mental model of how Neo4j works.

## 1. Fails: unwind(5)

From [the manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-using-unwind-with-an-expression-that-is-not-a-list):

> Attempting to use UNWIND on an expression that does not return a list — such as UNWIND 5 — will cause an error.

Indeed:

```
WITH 5 AS x 
UNWIND x AS y 
RETURN y
```

yields:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected List<T> but was Integer (line 2, column 8 (offset: 20))
"UNWIND x AS y "
        ^
```

## 2. Works: unwind( [ 1, [ 2, 3 ] ] )

Just as a preparation for the next step:

```
WITH [1, [2,3]] AS x 
UNWIND x AS y 
RETURN y
```

Spits:

```
╒═════╕
│"y"  │
╞═════╡
│1    │
├─────┤
│[2,3]│
└─────┘
```

Notice that the first row is `1` - not a list.

## 3. Works: unwind( unwind( [ 1, [ 2, 3 ] ] ) )

Surprise?

```
WITH [1, [2,3]] AS x 
UNWIND x AS y 
UNWIND y AS z 
RETURN z
```

Outputs:

```
╒═══╕
│"z"│
╞═══╡
│1  │
├───┤
│2  │
├───┤
│3  │
└───┘
```

So Neo is OK with the `1` in the nested unwind.

## 4. Fails: unwind( unwind( [ 1, 2 ] ) )

```
WITH [1, 2] AS x 
UNWIND x AS y 
UNWIND y AS z 
RETURN z
```

Errors:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected List<T> but was Integer (line 3, column 8 (offset: 40))
"UNWIND y AS z "
        ^
```

## How is this possible?

I just can't understand how, within a lazy context, unwind can selectively fail if an item is not a list, but only so long none of the (iterated) rows involve a list.

In other words, how come the `1` in case 3 is OK, but not in case 4?

For those interested, [here's the code for the unwind pipe](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.4.6/community/cypher/interpreted-runtime/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/runtime/interpreted/pipes/UnwindPipe.scala). There's nothing to suggest how the magic happens.

```
case class UnwindPipe(source: Pipe, collection: Expression, variable: String)
                     (val id: Id = Id.INVALID_ID)
  extends PipeWithSource(source) with ListSupport {

  collection.registerOwningPipe(this)

  protected def internalCreateResults(input: Iterator[ExecutionContext], state: QueryState): Iterator[ExecutionContext] = {
    if (input.hasNext) new UnwindIterator(input, state) else Iterator.empty
  }

  private class UnwindIterator(input: Iterator[ExecutionContext], state: QueryState) extends Iterator[ExecutionContext] {
    private var context: ExecutionContext = _
    private var unwindIterator: Iterator[AnyValue] = _
    private var nextItem: ExecutionContext = _

    prefetch()

    override def hasNext: Boolean = nextItem != null

    override def next(): ExecutionContext = {
      if (hasNext) {
        val ret = nextItem
        prefetch()
        ret
      } else Iterator.empty.next()
    }

    @tailrec
    private def prefetch() {
      nextItem = null
      if (unwindIterator != null && unwindIterator.hasNext) {
        nextItem = executionContextFactory.copyWith(context, variable, unwindIterator.next())
      } else {
        if (input.hasNext) {
          context = input.next()
          unwindIterator = makeTraversable(collection(context, state)).iterator.asScala
          prefetch()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the error message you posted

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected List
>   but was Integer (line 3, column 8 (offset: 40)) "UNWIND y AS z "

and then I notice that you posted the code for `UnwindPipe` it appears that you are looking at a tree and missing the forest.

So let me explain what I mean. I take it that you are looking in detail at the code for `UnwindPipe` and don't see any where in the code the reason for the error. However the error message is stating that you have a `SyntaxError` and not a `Run time error`. You see your problem yet?

The parser of the command is smart enough to know that you gave a list to the first `UNWIND` and then also smart enough to know that the result of that is not a list, yet  the second `UNWIND` needs a list and thus the parser responses with the error message. The code for `UnwindPipe` was never called or executed as the parsing of the input command failed.

Comment: This is definitely a good hypothesis, reinforced by the fact that you see a similar error in a [test branded Semantic](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/97a7aed10af8c0a0c70240a37fe2bed5b42856fa/enterprise/cypher/acceptance-spec-suite/src/test/scala/org/neo4j/internal/cypher/acceptance/SemanticErrorAcceptanceTest.scala#L50). But, and it's a big But, if you run case 4 in http://console.neo4j.org/, you get `org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException`.

Comment: Now the thing is that parser takes [expression for WITH](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/blob/master/grammar/cypher.xml#L315), (so is UNWIND). Now I seriously doubt that at the point of parsing the parser has any understanding of this - it is the planner that builds the operator graph and it should keep score of what it variables it has at each point and their type (for optimisation). So if anything, this should happen at the planer level - not parser.

Comment: Although you may be right after all. This could be where it throws (ast part of the parser): https://github.com/opencypher/front-end/blob/9.0/ast/src/main/scala/org/opencypher/v9_0/ast/Clause.scala#L533 Only problem is: How do I confirm this?

Comment: No need to go into these lengths, Guy. Just needed a lead and I think I've found one. In the course, I've also discovered openChypher/frontend - which is a hell of a find. Also logisima's pretty much confirms what you have said. Thanks!

Comment: Of interest: [Tuning Your Cypher: Tips & Tricks for More Effective Queries](https://neo4j.com/blog/tuning-cypher-queries/) Has a nice graphic that shows pipeline of processing a cypher query; includes `parsing` and `semantic analysis` steps.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you use parameters in your query, the 1) is working !

`:params { data:5}`

```
WITH $data AS x 
UNWIND x AS y 
RETURN y
```

Comment: OK. That kind of supports Guy's answer - that the error is from the parsing stage and not the execution one. I think this works because of this line (triggered from the UNWIND pipe): https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/97a7aed10af8c0a0c70240a37fe2bed5b42856fa/community/cypher/cypher-planner-3.5/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v3_5/helpers/ListSupport.scala#L84